# Skip lines without commas

Tags: r, csv

I have a huge csv file and I want to import it to R for some analysis. Some of the lines inside the csv doesnt have any commas and need to be discarded.

How can R reads csv line by line and skip those lines?

As an example, here is list

```
id,length,height
1,70,50
2,82,40
3,64,30
these lines
should be discarded
4,48,22
5,32,14
```

my desired imported data in R:

```
id,length,height
1,70,50
2,82,40
3,64,30
4,48,22
5,32,14
```

Edit: I applogize that I didnt send a good example. How can we improve the answer for this data.I need an answer that can detect lines without comma not an answer that detects lines without number.

```
id,length,height
1,70,50
2,82,40
3,64,30
rsammsa='b'
sdasdsa='a'
sadas='021210'
@sss
4,48,22
5,32,14
```

with desired output as before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can read the data using `readLines` and then remove the lines that has all non-numeric characters along with space from first (`^`) to last (`$`) using `grep`.  Read the subset of lines with `read.table/read.csv`

```
lines <- readLines("yourfile.txt")
lines1 <- lines[!grepl("^[A-Za-z ]+$", lines)]
dat <- read.table(text=lines1, sep=",",
             header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dat
#   id length height
#1  1     70     50
#2  2     82     40
#3  3     64     30
#4  4     48     22
#5  5     32     14
```

#### Update

Based on the new data showed by the OP, we can modify the `grep`

```
lines1 <- lines[c(TRUE,!grepl('[^0-9,]', lines[-1]))]
```

and then read as before

```
dat <- read.table(text=lines1, sep=",",
         header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dat
#   id length height
#1  1     70     50
#2  2     82     40
#3  3     64     30
#4  4     48     22 
#5  5     32     14
```

Comment: sure. as soon as I run it in my pc :-)

Comment: I found what is the problem. In my real data, I also have letters inside those lines with comma. your solution works perfectly for my example. Can grep modified in a way that it detect those lines without comma?

Comment: Well, I think it was unfair that I modified the quesiton later. I try my best to find an answer based on your answer.http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317586/question-with-improper-example

Comment: @Woeistg  It's okay.  I modifed my code.  Please check if that works.

Comment: I modified the code so that now it accepts also letters inside csv. feel free to restore it back. Also I add a complete list of operators so if somebody needs to personalize the pattern, it will be easier.

Comment: @Woeistg  Your edit seems to be rejected by the community.  I will add as a comment.

Comment: @Woeistg The dot part by itself matches any character.  But inside the `[]` it should match only the `.`.  So I am not sure `lines1 <- lines[c(TRUE,grepl('[•,]', lines[-1]))]`  should serve the purpose.

Comment: never mind. for my own data, your code didnt work because I also had letters between commas such as `1b,2,23`. with my modification, it also works for me.